# Is $p\geq 3$ a prime divisor of $\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{sm}$ where $m$ divides $p-1~?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Is it always true that  $p\geq 3$ **not** a prime divisor of
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{sm}
> \end{equation*}
> where $m$ divides $p-1~?$

The following is my attempt, and I made some simplifications in order to conclude something. But it seems not to be very helpful. Any comments or advice would be grateful.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{sm}&=\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\left(\binom{tm}{0}+\binom{tm}{m}+\binom{tm}{2m}+\cdots+\binom{tm}{p-1-m}\right)\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\left(1+\binom{tm}{m}+\binom{tm}{2m}+\cdots+\binom{tm}{p-1-m}\right)\\
&=\frac{p-1}{m}+\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{m}+\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{2m}+\cdots+\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{p-1-m}\\
&=\frac{p-1}{m}+\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{m}+\sum_{t=2}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{2m}+\cdots+\sum_{t=\frac{p-1}{m}-1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{p-1-m}\\
&=1+\frac{p-1}{m}+\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{m}+\sum_{t=2}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{2m}+\cdots+\sum_{t=\frac{p-1}{m}-2}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{p-1-2m}
\end{align*}

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true for $p=7$, $m=3$? I get that the sum is $\binom{0}{0}+\binom{0}{3}+\binom{3}{0}+\binom{3}{3} = 1+0+1+1=3$, which isn't divisible by $7$. Is there a typo?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thanks for your comment, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$I will prove the following:

> **Theorem** Let $m$ be odd. Then there is a constant $N$ such that, if $p$ a prime which is $1 \bmod m$ and $>N$, then the sum in question is $0 \bmod p$.

Thanks to [mathlove's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746253/448) for many of the key ideas in this answer.

---

To start with, take no hypotheses on $m$ and let $p$ be a prime which is $1 \bmod m$. Since $p \equiv 1 \bmod m$, there are $m$ distinct $m$-th roots of unity in $\FF_p$, call them $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, ..., $\gamma_m$.

Note that we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-2} (\gamma_i+\gamma_j)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{p-2} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \gamma_i^k \gamma_j^{n-k}.$$
Summing on $i$ and $j$, we get
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^m \sum_{n=0}^{p-2} (\gamma_i+\gamma_j)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{p-2} \sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i,j=1}^m \gamma_i^k \gamma_j^{n-k}.$$
The inner sum is $m^2$ if $k \equiv n-k \equiv 0 \bmod m$, and is $0$ otherwise, so we get that $\sum_{i,j=1}^m \sum_{n=0}^{p-2} (\gamma_i+\gamma_j)^n$ is $m^2$ times the sum in question.

Now, for $a \in \FF_p$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-2} a^n = \begin{cases} 1 & a =0 \\ p-1 & a = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
To see the last case, note that, for $a \neq 0$, $1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-2} a^n = \frac{a^{p-1}-1}{a-1} = 0.$$

Thus, we need to understand whether $\gamma_i+\gamma_j$ could be $0$ or $1$. Our result will follow from proving the following two lemmas:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $m$ be odd. If $p$ is a prime $>2$ which is $1 \bmod m$ and $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, ..., $\gamma_m$ are the $m$-th roots of unity modulo $p$, then $\gamma_i+\gamma_j \neq 0$.

> **Lemma 2:** Let $m$ not be divisible by $6$. Then there is a constant $N$ such that, if $p$ is a prime $>N$ which is $1 \bmod m$ and $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, ..., $\gamma_m$ are the $m$-th roots of unity modulo $p$, then $\gamma_i+\gamma_j \neq 1$.

Lemma 1 is easier.

**Proof of Lemma 1** Suppose that $\gamma_i+\gamma_j = 0$. Then $-1 = \gamma_i \gamma_j^{-1}$, so $-1$ is an $m$-th root of unity. But $m$ is odd and $p>2$, a contradiction. $\square$

To prove Lemma 2, we use [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

**Lemma 3** For $p$ a prime which is $1 \bmod m$, there are two $m$-th roots of unity in $\FF_p$ with sum $1$ if and only if $p$ divides one of the $m^2$ many resultants $R(x^a+x^b-1, x^m-1)$ for $0 \leq a,b \leq m-1$.

**Proof:** We recall that $R(x^a+x^b-1, x^m-1) = 0 \bmod p$ if and only if $x^a+x^b-1$ and $x^m-1$ have a common root in the algebraic closure $\overline{\FF}_p$. Since $p \equiv 1 \bmod m$, all roots of $x^m-1$ in $\overline{\FF}_p$ in fact lie in $\FF_p$.

So, if $\zeta$ is a common root of $x^a+x^b-1$ and $x^m-1$, then $\zeta^a$ and $\zeta^b$ are two $m$-th roots of unity in $\FF_p$ summing to $1$.

Conversely, suppose that we have two $m$-th roots of unity, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, in $\FF_p$, which sum to $1$. The group of $m$-th roots of unity in $\FF_p$ is cyclic; let $\zeta$ be a generator and let $\alpha = \zeta^a$ and $\beta = \zeta^b$. Then $\zeta$ is a common root of $x^m-1$ and $x^a+x^b-1$ in $\FF_p$. So we have proven the equivalence. $\square$

Lemma 1 will follow from Lemma 3 as long as none of the resultants $R(x^a+x^b-1, x^m-1)$ are $0$ (just take $N$ larger than any of these resultants). So, to finish the problem, we must show:

**Lemma 4:** Let $m$ be not divisible by $6$. Then the restultant $R(x^a+x^b-1, x^m-1)$ is not $0$ for any $0 \leq a,b \leq m-1$.

**Proof:** If $R(x^a+x^b-1, x^m-1)=0$, then the polynomials $x^a+x^b-1$ and $x^m-1$ have a common root in $\CC$. So there are two $m$-th roots of unity in $\CC$ which add to $1$. But the only two numbers on the unit circle which sum to $1$ are $\tfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$, which are primitive $6$-th roots of unity. So, since $m$ is not divisible by $6$, these are not $m$-th roots of unity. $\square$

This concludes the proof of the Theorem.

---

I'll note that the prime factors of these resultants can be surprisingly large! Here is a table of all the factors for the first few values of $m$:

```
m     prime factors of resultants
3     2, 7
5     11, 31
7     2, 29, 127
9     2, 7, 19, 37, 73
11    23, 67, 89, 199
13    3, 53, 79, 131, 521, 8191
```

---

I haven't checked this as carefully, but you should be able to use the same argument to work out what the sum equals when $m$ is even, and $p$ is large enough not to divide any of the nonzero resultants. I believe that, for $m \equiv 2,4 \bmod 6$, the sum is $\tfrac{1}{m^2} m$ (coming from the $m$ pairs $(\zeta, - \zeta)$ of $m$-th roots of unity summing to $0$) and, for $m \equiv 0 \bmod 6$, we get $\tfrac{1}{m^2} (m-2)$, where we add in the $m$ pairs $(\zeta, - \zeta)$ as above, and then subtract of $2$ for $(\eta, \eta^{-1})$ and $(\eta^{-1}, \eta)$, where $\eta$ is a primitive $6$-th root of unity.

Comment: Nice answer! On a different note, I am the one who posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453698/512645) and received your excellent answer. We have been trying to contact you via your email for the last few days regarding the question mentioned and are afraid that you might have missed it. We would be glad if you can get back to us about it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$S(m,p):=\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\binom{tm}{sm}$$

In the following, let us prove the followings :

- $S(1,p)$ is divisible by $p$.
- $S(2,p)$ is not divisible by $p$.
- $S(3,7)$ is not divisible by $7$.
- If $p\ge 13$, then $S(3,p)$ is divisible by $p$.
- $S(4,p)$ is not divisible by $p$.
- $S(5,11)$ is not divisible by $11$.
- $S(5,31)$ is not divisible by $31$.
- If $p\ge 41$, then $S(5,p)$ is divisible by $p$.

---

Using that $\binom nk=0$ when $n\lt k$, $S(m,p)$ can be simplified as
$$S(m,p)=\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{tm}{sm}$$

Here, we have
$$\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{tm}{sm}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $m\ge 1$ and $t=0$}
\\\\ 2^t&\text{if $m=1$ and $t\ge 1$}
\\\\ \dfrac{2^{tm}}{m}+\dfrac{2^{tm+1}}{m}\displaystyle\sum^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\cos^{tm}\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg)&\text{if $m\ge 2$ and $t\ge 1$}\end{cases}$$

(A proof is written at the end of this answer.)

Therefore, for $m\ge 2$, we get
$$\begin{align}S(m,p)&=\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{tm}{sm}
\\\\&=1+\bigg(\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\dfrac{2^{tm}}{m}\bigg)+\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\dfrac{2^{tm+1}}{m}\displaystyle\sum^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\cos^{tm} \frac{k\pi}{m}
\\\\&=1+\frac{2^{p-1}-2^m}{m(2^m-1)}+\frac 2m\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{m}-1}\sum^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\bigg(2\cos\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg)^{tm}\end{align}$$

---

For $m=1$,
$$S(1,p)=\sum_{t=0}^{p-2}\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{t}{s}=1+\sum_{t=1}^{p-2}2^t=2^{p-1}-1$$ Since $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, this is divisible by $p$.

---

For $m=2$,
$$S(2,p)=\frac{2^{p-1}+2}{6}+\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}-1}(-1)^{t}\bigg(2\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)^{2t}=\frac{2^{p-2}+1}{3}$$
This is not divisible by $p$.

---

For $m=3$,
$$S(3,p)=\frac{2^{p-1}+13}{21}+\frac 23\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-4}{3}}(-1)^{t}=\frac{2^{p-1}+13}{21}-\frac 23=\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{21}$$

- $S(3,7)=3$ is not divisible by $7$.
- If $p\ge 13$, then $S(3,p)$ is divisible by $p$.

---

For $m=4$,
$$\begin{align}S(4,p)&=\frac{2^{p-1}+44}{60}+\frac 12\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{4}-1}\sum^{2}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\bigg(2\cos\frac{k\pi}{4}\bigg)^{4t}
\\\\&=\frac{2^{p-1}+44}{60}+\frac 12\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{4}-1}(-4)^t
\\\\&=\frac{2^{p-1}+20-6(-4)^{(p-1)/4}}{60}\end{align}$$

This is not divisible by $p$.

(The reason is as follows : If this is divisible by $p$, we have to have
$$7\equiv 2(-4)^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p\implies 7^4\equiv 16\pmod p\implies p=5,53$$
which are not sufficient.)

---

For $m=5$,

With help of [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282%2F5%29*%28%28%28%28%28%28-1-sqrt%285%29%29%2F2%29%5E%28p-1%29%29-%28%28%28-1-sqrt%285%29%29%2F2%29%5E5%29%29%2F%28%28%28%28-1-sqrt%285%29%29%2F2%29%5E5%29-1%29%29%2B%28%28%28%28+%28%28sqrt%285%29%29-1%29%2F2%29%5E%28p-1%29%29-%28%28+%28%28sqrt%285%29%29-1%29%2F2%29%5E5%29%29%2F%28%28%28+%28%28sqrt%285%29%29-1%29%2F2%29%5E5%29-1%29%29%29+),

$$\begin{align}S(5,p)&=\frac{2^{p-1}+123}{155}+\frac 25\sum_{t=1}^{\frac{p-1}{5}-1}\sum^{2}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\bigg(2\cos\frac{k\pi}{5}\bigg)^{5t}
\\\\&=\frac{2^{p-1}+123}{155}
\\&\qquad -\frac{9\cdot 2^{p + 1} - (19 - 9 \sqrt 5) (\sqrt 5+1)^p + (19 + 9 \sqrt 5) (\sqrt 5 - 1)^p}{55\cdot 2^p}  
\\\\&=\frac{A}{5\times 11\times 31\times 2^p}\end{align}$$

where
$$\begin{align}A&=11\cdot 2^p(2^{p-1}+123)-31\cdot 9\cdot 2^{p+1}
\\&\qquad +31(19-9\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 5+1)^p-31(19+9\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 5-1)^p
\\\\&=11\cdot 2^{2p-1}+795\cdot 2^p+31\times 19\bigg((\sqrt 5+1)^p-(\sqrt 5-1)^p\bigg)
\\&\qquad -31\times 9\sqrt 5\bigg((\sqrt 5+1)^p+(\sqrt 5-1)^p\bigg)
\\\\&=11\cdot 2^{2p-1}+795\cdot 2^p+31\times 19\sum_{i=1}^{(p+1)/2}\binom{p}{2i-1}2(\sqrt 5)^{p-(2i-1)}
\\&\qquad -31\times 9\sum_{i=0}^{(p-1)/2}\binom{p}{2i}2(\sqrt 5)^{p-2i+1}\end{align}$$

- $S(5,11)=3$ is not divisible by $11$.
- $S(5,31)=6865813$ is not divisible by $31$.
- If $p\ge 41$, then $S(5,p)$ is divisible by $p$.

(The reason is as follows : Since $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $\binom pi\equiv 0\pmod p$ when $1\le i\le p-1$, we have $A\equiv 2790-2790(\frac 5p)\equiv 2790-2790\frac{1}{(\frac p5)}\equiv 0\pmod p$ where $(\frac{b}{a})$ denotes the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Since the denominator has $11$ and $31$, it is sufficient that $p\ge 41$.)

---

In the following, let us prove that if $m\ge 2$ and $t\ge 1$, then

$$\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{tm}{sm}=\dfrac{2^{tm}}{m}+\dfrac{2^{tm+1}}{m}\displaystyle\sum^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\cos^{tm}\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg)$$

*Proof* :

Let $\omega:=\cos\frac{2\pi}{m}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{m}$. Let us consider
$$\begin{align}(1+1)^n&=\binom n0+\binom n1+\binom n2+\cdots +\binom nn
\\\\(1+\omega)^n&=\binom n0+\binom n1\omega+\binom n2\omega^2 +\cdots +\binom nn\omega^n
\\\\&\vdots
\\\\(1+\omega^{m-1})^n&=\binom n0+\binom n1\omega^{m-1}+\binom n2(\omega^{m-1})^2+\cdots +\binom nn(\omega^{m-1})^n
\end{align}$$

For $k$ such that $m\not\mid k$, the sum of the coefficients of $\binom nk$ is
$$1+\omega^k+\omega^{2k}+\cdots +(\omega^{m-1})^k=\frac{\omega^{mk}-1}{\omega^k-1}=0$$
so we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(1+\omega^k)^n=m\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor}\binom{n}{sm}$$

Therefore, we can write
$$\begin{align}\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor}\binom{n}{sm}&=\frac 1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(1+\omega^k)^n
\\\\&=\frac 1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\bigg(1+\cos\frac{2k\pi}{m}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{m}\bigg)^n
\\\\&=\frac 1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\bigg(2\cos^2\frac{k\pi}{m}+2i\cos\frac{k\pi}{m}\sin\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg)^n
\\\\&=\frac 1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}2^n\cos^n\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg(\cos\frac{kn\pi}{m}+i\sin\frac{kn\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{m}+\frac{2^n}{m}\sum_{k=\color{red}1}^{m-1}f(k)\end{align}$$
where
$$f(k)=\cos^n\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg(\cos\frac{kn\pi}{m}+i\sin\frac{kn\pi}{m}\bigg)$$

Since

- If $m$ is even, then $f(\lfloor m/2\rfloor)=0$
- $f(m-k)=\cos^n\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg(\cos\frac{kn\pi}{m}\color{red}-i\sin\frac{kn\pi}{m}\bigg)$

we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor}\binom{n}{sm}&=\frac{2^n}{m}+\frac{2^n}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}f(k)
\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{m}+\frac{2^n}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\bigg(f(k)+f(m-k)\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{m}+\frac{2^n}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}2\cos^n\frac{k\pi}{m}\cos\frac{kn\pi}{m}\end{align}$$

Therefore, for $n=tm$, we have
$$\sum_{s=0}^{t}\binom{tm}{sm}=\dfrac{2^{tm}}{m}+\dfrac{2^{tm+1}}{m}\displaystyle\sum^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}_{k=1}(-1)^{kt}\cos^{tm}\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{m}\bigg).\ \blacksquare$$